# Need to Format Current Date in Specific Format in React Native using Libraries

Tags: reactjs, date, datetime, react-native

Actually in my app. I am trying to display current date & time in a specific format like this " 27/02/2019 1:40 PM ". I have done this by making use of custom formatting codes. But what i actually need is, I need to achieve this by making use of libraries.

Thanks for helping.!

Using this:(Manually formatting Date & Time)

```
var d = new Date();
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hours = d.getHours();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; 
var min = d.getMinutes();
min = min < 10 ? '0'+min : min;
var result = date + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ' ' + ampm;
console.log(result); //Prints DateTime in the above specified format
```

Comment: momentjs is your best shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `moment.js` https://momentjs.com/

`moment().format('DD/MM/YY h:mm A')` will give you your desired output.

Comment: Thank you for the quick shot reply.! 
I had made use of moment.js as you told. It is working perfect.!

Comment: You can also try https://date-fns.org/ it has smaller footprint then moment.js with almost the same functionality.